# Firebase real time database returning a null value, TypeError: row is null

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

What I am trying to do is to get the data from the firebase realtime database through a nodejs application and from there allow the frontend to make requests directly to my node application and not to the firebase. I made the request to the firebase database, just like the code below but it returns a null value and when the frontend reads this value it generates an error. I already checked in the firebase database and there is no null value. The firebase returns all data as it should, but it always returns this "null", just like the image below.

```
{
  "data": [
    null,
    {
      "data": "12/04/2016",
      "subtitulo": "test...",
      "titulo": "test"
    },
    {
      "data": "05/05/2019",
      "subtitulo": "test...",
      "titulo": "test"
    },
    {
      "data": "02/01/2020",
      "subtitle": "title",
      "title": "test"
    }
  ]
}
```

Node Js code:

```
db.ref('myreference/here/').once('value', (snapshot) => {
      data = snapshot.val();

      return res.json({
        data,
      });
    });
```

Error generated by React Js when I request the api:
[image: Error generated by React Js when I request the api]

[image]

Comment: Can you please share a screenshot of a record in the firestore?

Comment: Done! I'm using real time database, @Michael

Comment: my assumption is that you for some reason have one document which is `null` as it says in the docs: " If no data exists at the reference's location, the snapshot's value is null". Here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#node.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the Firebase Realtime Database doesn't natively store arrays, it's APIs and SDKs try to handle arrays in the source data gracefully. When you store an array, they convert it to a JSON map with sequential, numeric keys (`"0"`, `"1"`, etc). And then you read such a structure back from the database, they convert it to an array.

That last action is what you see in your code: since your keys look like array indexes, the client converts the data to an array. And since key `"0"` is missing, it inserts a `null` element in the array for that.

The easiest way to circumvent this array coercion is by add a prefix to your keys, like:

```
"Avisos": {
  "key1": { ... },
  "key2": { ... },
  "key2": { ... },
}
```

That will ensure the Firebase API/SDK doesn't coerce the data into an array.

In general, I recommend not using sequential numeric keys (Kato gives a good overview in [Best Practices: Arrays in Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html)), but instead use the [keys generated by Firebase's `push()` method](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/02/the-2120-ways-to-ensure-unique_68.html).